# django success messages printed in admin site rather than pages

Tags: python, django, django-messages

After a version upgrade from 1.11.1 to 1.11.4 success messages are not displayed in pages but in admin site. what has to be changed...

```
       messages.success(request, 'denetim başarıyla kaydedildi......')
        #return render(request, 'islem/tek_sayfa.html', context,)
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        messages.success(request, ' form hatası - tekrar deneyin....')
        return redirect('teksayfa_yarat')
```

Comment: 1.11.4 is a minor release - it's really unlikely that the upgrade from 1.11.1 is causing the problem, especially when the messages framework has been stable for years. Your links to google drive don't work, but you should really include the relevant code in your question instead of linking to another site. Please show the views that you redirect to, and how you display the messages in those templates.

Comment: After upgrade  raise forms.validationerror  method also does not work. I have asked this in my previous question...      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671146/django-validation-error-does-not-work      can this bu something related to settings..

Comment: Again, I'd be really surprised if the upgrade from Django 1.11.1 to 1.11.4 caused a problem with `forms.ValidationError`. There's too much code and the explanation isn't clear on that question, so I didn't answer it. O don't know what you mean by "does not work", but the comments on this question aren't the best place to discuss that.